# Rails 3.1 precompilation error in production for SWF file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a few .swf files that are being added to a project via a git submodule. They live in /vendor/private/widget/

To get the .swf files into the asset pipeline I'm doing the following:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/private/widget"
```

In development this works just fine, but in production I get the following error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (widget.swf isn't precompiled):

After searching around StackOverflow, I've tried these two solutions, both of which did not work:

```
config.assets.precompile << '*.swf'

config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: What helper (and path) are you using to access the swf file? Have a look in the manifest.yml for the swf as this may give you an indication of how Rails expects the file to pathed in the helper.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting application.rb 's

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

to

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

for the precompile, and flip it back to true afterwards.  I don't know why this works or what part of the url digest would be preventing the asset inclusion, but this has been the only way i've found to be able to generate my assets in production to include swf files.

Comment: While this will get the asset precompile to work it doesn't append the has tag to the URLs which were generated so your rails server would get hit every time to serve up the static file defeating the purpose of pre-compiling static files.

There must be something when generating the hash for swf files which cause the compiler to either fail, or generate two different hash values for the same file.